# Seat Geek API not responding to Jquery

Tags: jquery, api

I'm having trouble with the following jquery call to seatgeek. I'm trying to get Title information output on all events. I think I might be messing up some of the jquery notation. Does anyone know of what I might have done wrong?

```
<script>


  $.getJSON("http://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/?callback=?", function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.Title) {
        output+="<li>" + data.Title[i] +"</li>";
    }

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: There is no `data.Title` in the returned object! Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y2Ugy/)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `events` array within the `data` result object, and only *then*, access the `title` property (it's case sensitive):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/?callback=?", function(data) {
  var output="<ul>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {
    output += "<li>" + data.events[i].title +"</li>";          
  }            
  output += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TTgqu/)**.